# Typeahead.js dataset size limit

Tags: typeahead.js

For performance purposes, I'd prefer to include my entire dataset into a `local` or `prefetch` dataset but it seems like there may be a size limit. Can anyone confirm this, what the size limit is and if it's a typeahead.js thing or a broader constraint?

I've resorted to using a `remote` dataset where I return a subset of the data based on the initial query but this call has a performance cost although it seems like there's some decent caching going on that mitigates the problem.  Would be interested if anyone has any other creative approaches.

Comment: I haven't looked recently, but I don't recall seeing anything in source about size limitations. If that's true, then I am guessing it's the local storage being restrictive. To test that, try to pass a `local` object, but do *not* pass a `name` on the dataset, preventing it from going into storage.

Comment: Add `limit` to the dataset. iirc the default is 10, so you may want to increase that.

Comment: Found problem with my data - turns out @NitzanShaked comment was the answer

Comment: @NitzanShaked - if you put your comment as the answer, I'll accept

Comment: Glad that it worked for you. Added as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no inherent size limitation within the Typeahead.js code. It is most likely related to the fact that your data is store in localStorage. To circumvent that, remove the `name:` from the dataset (Typeahead doesn't use localStorage to cache datasets without a name).

Also, increase the dataset's `limit:` to suit your needs.